# Git: cannot rsync other branches to another repo

Tags: git, github, github-actions

My current workflow:

- Syncs my uk, it, nl & es branches so they are always the same as my master branch, within the same repo
- Afterwards rsyncs a compiled dist version of the master or dev branch to the dist repo

Goal:

- When pushing from master, and not dev/uk/it/nl/es, also perform the resync task so that the uk/it/nl/es branches get updated on the dist repo, next to the already working master sync. This doesn't seem to work as i do not push from one of these branches, so it's missing the ref: i *always* push from master. It seems the script expects the push to happen from one of these branches so it can catch the correct ref, and is able to perform the rsync to the dist repo.

Error: src refspec uk does not match any

Full workflow file is below. The code highlighted with # BELOW IS NOT WORKING is where it fails.

```
name: Build and Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - "master"
    - "dev"

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - name: Checkout the source repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0
      path: src

  - name: Setup node
    uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    with:
      node-version: 14

  - name: Build the source
    run: |
      cd src
      npm ci
      npm run webpack:build
      cd ..
  
  - name: Set Git identity
    run: |
      git config --global user.email "..."
      git config --global user.name "..."

  - name: Sync master to locale branches and push to remote
    run: |
      cd src
      for branch in uk nl es it; do
        git checkout $branch
        git fetch origin $branch

        if ! git merge-base --is-ancestor origin/$branch HEAD; then
          git merge -s recursive -X ours origin/$branch
          git checkout HEAD -- shopify/templates/product.json shopify/templates/index.json
          git add .
          git commit -m "Sync $branch with origin/$branch"
          git push origin $branch
        else
          echo "No new changes to sync for $branch."
        fi
      done

  - name: Checkout the dist repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      repository: ....
      path: dist
      ssh-key: ${{ secrets.ALPHAFOODS_DIST_PUSH_KEY }}
      ref: ${{ github.ref }}

  - name: Commit and push the changes to the dist repo
    run: |
      rsync -v -r --delete --exclude=.git/ src/shopify/ dist/

      cd src
      commit=`git rev-parse HEAD`
      cd ../dist

      git config user.name github-actions
      git config user.email github-actions@github.com
      
      git add .
      git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m "Built $commit"

      git push origin ${{ github.ref }}

      # BELOW IS NOT WORKING
      for branch in uk nl it es; do
        git push origin $branch
      done
```